# How to remove bullet icons when using UnorderedList component from ChakraUI

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

On https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/list/usage in their example (copy/pasted below)

```js
<List spacing={3}>
  <ListItem>
    <ListIcon as={MdCheckCircle} color='green.500' />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
  </ListItem>
  <ListItem>
    <ListIcon as={MdCheckCircle} color='green.500' />
    Assumenda, quia temporibus eveniet a libero incidunt suscipit
  </ListItem>
  <ListItem>
    <ListIcon as={MdCheckCircle} color='green.500' />
    Quidem, ipsam illum quis sed voluptatum quae eum fugit earum
  </ListItem>
  {/* You can also use custom icons from react-icons */}
  <ListItem>
    <ListIcon as={MdSettings} color='green.500' />
    Quidem, ipsam illum quis sed voluptatum quae eum fugit earum
  </ListItem>
</List>
```

In their example render, no bullet points appear. However, when I try this on Chrome (v108.0.5359.98), I see bullet icons.

I want to do the equivalent of `li {list-style-type: none;}`

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `styleType` prop should be used on `List`. E.g., if you want to remove the  bullets from an `UnorderdList` list you can use this instead of specifying it on each `ListItem`.

```
<UnorderdList styleType="none">
```

Comment: Thanks, I've chosen this as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListItem listStyleType='none' key='whatever-key'>
```

This should fix it. For some reason, their [props](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/list/props) mention `styleType` but only `listStyleType` works for me.